# Django DatabaseError: relation "django_site"

Tags: django, postgresql-9.2

I currently have a django app am developing on my PC with data in my db but when i try running this app on a test server i get the error below

```
DatabaseError: relation "django_site" does not exist
LINE 1: ..."django_site"."domain", "django_site"."name" FROM "django_si...
```

can any one tell me why am getting this error please.thanks

Comment: Did you sync the database on the test server?

Comment: yes i did syncd the be and thats when i get that error i also tried running manage.py runserver and still the error is still same

Comment: Did you alter or not include the SITE_ID setting in settings.py such that the SITE_ID doesn't correlate to a record in the django_site table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not been able to solve this a django way so i tried using sql, i created a dump of just the database like this.

```
pg_dump mypgdatabase | gzip -c > mypgdatabase.dump.out.gz
```

then moved it to the server

```
scp /path/to/mypgdatabase.dump.out.gz  my_remote_server
```

then recreated it on the server like this

```
psql -d mypgdatabase -f mypgdatabase.dump.out
```

then run

```
./manange.py migrate --all
```

and all when well.

Answer (score 8):

**You may be calling a site object before creating site model(before syncdb)**

ex:    site = Site.objects.get(id=settings.SITE_ID)

Answer (score 5):

This issue continues to plague many, including myself. Although a tedious process, this approach saves me the brain power:

Disable all external apps in your INSTALLED_APPS, except your own apps, like so:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.flatpages',
    'main', # This is my own app.

    # 'compressor',
    # 'ckeditor',
    # 'imagekit',
    # 'debug_toolbar',
    # 'rest_framework',
    # 'allauth',
    # 'allauth.account',
    # 'allauth.socialaccount',

    # 'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
    # 'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
)
```

Run

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Then, uncomment all the other apps, then repeat makemigrations and migrate above.

That works **all the time for me**

Comment: Thank god its not only me that has this issue.

Answer (score 4):

I can't see your models or what apps are you using, but my guess is that you are using django_site (Site model) and you don't have 'django.contrib.sites' in the INSTALLED_APPS.

If I'm correct then just add `'django.contrib.sites',` to your `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Comment: i have django.contrib.sites installed

Answer (score 4):

Had this strange issue while initiating a new database and using django-debug-toolbar. Removed it from the `INSTALLED_APPS` and was able to run `syncdb`. Then re-added debug_toolbar and it was still working fine.

If you're using django-debug-toolbar, try to comment out `debug_toolbar` in your installed apps and try again.

---

Update: Please follow the steps for the explicit setup: http://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.org/en/1.2.2/installation.html#explicit-setup

Comment: Tried this, didn't work. I'm on django 1.8 and using postgresql

Answer (score 3):

i have same problem and fixed it like this:

1. add `SITE_ID=1` into `settings.py`
2. run this command :

   python manage.py migrate

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things you can try and check:

- Your `settings.py` should have a `SITE_ID` usually `= 1`
- Change order of your `INSTALLED_APPS` in your `settings.py` and try temporarily commenting items out.
- As Geo said, check that you're not calling a site object before creating site model (ex: `site = Site.objects.get(id=settings.SITE_ID)`).

Once you got it working, remember to `manage.py makemigrations APP_NAME` as I found cases where it seem to have then avoided the commenting out step.

Answer (score 0):

I overcame this issue with the following order in `INSTALLED_APPS`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'allauth',                                                                 
    'allauth.account',                                                         
    # my other apps,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

My "commenting out" pattern was slightly different than the accepted answers (as shown below). That is to say, it might be unique depending on the values of various dependencies scattered throughout your app. If commenting out the values above throws an error message, I recommend commenting out the apps that throw the error message and uncommenting accordingly until it works for you. This may be a little "brute force" but it should get the job done.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # django native apps
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    "django.forms",
    'django.contrib.gis',
    # 'django.contrib.flatpages',
    #third party apps
    #django-allauth apps
    'allauth',
    # 'allauth.account',
    # 'allauth.socialaccount',
    # 'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
    # 'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
    # 'allauth.socialaccount.providers.twitter',
    # 'allauth.socialaccount.providers.github',
    # my apps
    'app0',
    'app1',]

#MIGRATION_MODULES = {"sites": "mysite.contrib.sites.migrations"}
```

Answer (score -2):

Also make sure SITE_ID = 1 comes before the DATABASE definition in settings.py

Comment: I don't see how that could affect anything. DATABASES and SITE_ID are both variable that get assigned to strings, and those settings are loaded by Django, no matter the order it'll have no effect at all (quite unlike the order of the apps in the list).